# Can you store multiple arrays in one session?

Tags: php, ajax, session

Can you push multiple arrays to one session?

**For example**

```
array_push($_SESSION['mySession'], $array);
```

**Problem:** When i push another array to my session it **removes** tha last one in the session.

My case:

Get specific item from database

```
$meubel = $_GET['meubel'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mphp6_meubels WHERE naam LIKE '$meubel' ";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
```

Make new session if its does not exists:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['meubels'])){
    $_SESSION['meubels'] = array();
}
```

Make specific array

```
    while($row = $stm->fetch()){
        $meubel = [
            'naam' => $row['naam'],
            'type' => $row['type'],
            'omschrijving' => $row['omschrijving'],
            'prijs' => $row['prijs'],
        ];
}
```

**push it to session**

```
array_push($_SESSION['meubels'], $meubel);
```

When a button is clicked an ajax reqeust is made:

```
var url = 'test.php?meubel=' + meubel;
```

**Output** the session in a div

```
document.getElementById("div3").innerHTML = result;
```

*If all ajax code is required please tell me.*

**Example:**

When you buy a seat add it to the session. A seat has property's like: name, description and price. So the session must contain multiple arrays.

[image]

Comment: You could try `$_SESSION['meubels'] = array_merge($_SESSION['meubels'], $meubel)`

Answer (score 2):

You are redefining `$meubel` each time through the loop so there is only one array.  You want to dynamically append each row `[]`:

```
while($row = $stm->fetch()){
    $meubel[] = [
        'naam' => $row['naam'],
        'type' => $row['type'],
        'omschrijving' => $row['omschrijving'],
        'prijs' => $row['prijs'],
    ];
}
```

Then you probably want to merge instead of push, not sure what end result you want:

```
$_SESSION['meubels'] = array_merge($_SESSION['meubels'], $meubel);
```

Comment: I want my session "meubels" to have multiple arrays "meubel".

Comment: You would need to show an example of the resulting array that you want.

Comment: I've added a example in the question. Please tell if its not clear to you.

Comment: two dimensional array its called, i believe.

Comment: But your right i redefining `$meubel`, every time i fetch the specific row from the database it must add it to the session array.